# Rgooglemaps plotting of text

Tags: r, rgooglemaps

I am using the Rgooglemaps package in R.

I want to display text over plotted point using `PlotOnStaticMap`. There is also function named `TextOnStaticMap` for plotting text on specified coordinates.

But in the output map either text is printed or points are plotted, but i need both.

Comment: Shameless plug: As an alternative to Rgooglemaps, you may want to check out DeducerSpatial, which was just released to CRAN http://blog.fellstat.com/?p=89

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to feed in the `add=TRUE` option to the relevant function. If it's `FALSE` (the default) you get a new plot.

```
PlotOnStaticMap(MyMap,lat=..,lon=..,FUN=points)
TextOnStaticMap(MyMap,lat=..,lon=..,labels=.., add=TRUE) # <- adds to current map
```

Note, you can just use `PlotOnStaticMap` for all of this with different `FUN` (for example `text`,`points`,`lines` - the usual plotting functions):

```
PlotOnStaticMap(MyMap,lat=..,lon=..,FUN=points)
PlotOnStaticMap(MyMap,lat=..,lon=..,FUN=text, labels=.., add=TRUE)
```